# getchar gives output in the wrong order

Tags: c

The program should give output in the following way:

Enter a character

g

Successfully entered!

g

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int c,d ;

  printf("Enter a character\n");
  c = getchar();
  printf("Successfully entered!\n");
  putchar(c);

return(0);

}
```

But when it is run, it waits for the user to enter the input before asking for it and then prints out in the following way:

g

Enter a character

Successfully entered!

g

Comment: I am sure it will not! Post the actual code.

Comment: I agree with @haccks.

Comment: Most likely reason is, you have full buffering mode enabled. Add more details to the question. As it is currently written, the code you show does work.

Comment: This is not the actual code, there is no way that this code will give the output you say is giving.

Comment: It does. I rechecked it again. I have tried flushing the input buffers and taking care of the '\n'. But it has no affect on the output. I think there might be an implementation issue. I am running windows.

Comment: @user3272983 , My crystal ball tells me you are using eclipse IDE. Right?

Comment: @Cool Guy: Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

You may put a fllush after the printf before getchar

```
  printf("Enter a character\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  c = getchar();
```

fflush is meant to be called on an output stream. This is an excerpt from the C standard:

```
int fflush(FILE *ostream);

ostream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
```

Comment: @haccks: Is `fflush()` on `stdin` correct?

Comment: @1336087; No. Read [it](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).